# Deep link URL Scheme doesn't call any function in iOS App Delegate

Tags: ios, swift, deep-linking, url-scheme

im implementing deep link is iOS. I have configured the URL Scheme in Project-Setting->Info->Url type
URL Schemes :  carwash    role:Viewer

when I type carwash://something the browser asks for opening the application but nothing get called in Application that I handle that what action should occur .

apple documentation says you should override application(open url) in AppDelegate but deep link dosent call it and the application opens in last state

application:openURL:options:' is not being called

this is my code and dose not work

```
func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL,
                     options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
    fatalError()
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    if let url = launchOptions?[UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey.url] as? URL {
        /// some
        fatalError()
    }
    GMSServices.provideAPIKey("")

    return true
}
```

Comment: You need to ```return true``` in your ```open url``` delegate method.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Method 'application:openURL:options:' is not called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58624786/method-applicationopenurloptions-is-not-called)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In iOS 13, `UIApplication` `application(_:open:options:)` doesn't get called (at least in my case maybe).

You should override the SceneDelegate functions below instead:

```
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, openURLContexts URLContexts: Set<UIOpenURLContext>) {
    if let url = URLContexts.first?.url{
        print(url) 
    }
}

func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
    // detect the URLContext in the `options:` and deal with it.
}
```

If the user taps the link when your app isn't running, `scene(_: openURLContexts:)` won't be called but `scene(_:willConnectTo:options:)` will be.

Comment: Half right. That won't work if the URL arrives when your app isn't running.

Comment: then what do you suggest ?

Comment: It's not a matter of what I "suggest", it's a fact. You have to implement `scene(_:willConnectTo:options:)` to detect the URLContext in the `options:` and deal with it. Otherwise, if the user taps the link when your app isn't running, you won't respond to it. Try it and you'll see.

Comment: Thank you crystal sphere matt. Really helpful comment.

Answer (score 2):

in iOS 13+ or scene delegate there two methods will call and willPerformHTTPRedirection method will definitely call.

```
  func scene(_ scene: UIScene, continue userActivity: NSUserActivity) {
        if userActivity.activityType == NSUserActivityTypeBrowsingWeb, let url =      userActivity.webpageURL {
          
        }
      }
    }

 func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, task: URLSessionTask, willPerformHTTPRedirection response: HTTPURLResponse, newRequest request: URLRequest, completionHandler: @escaping (URLRequest?) -> Swift.Void) {
            if let url = request.url {
               guard let detailDictionary = String.queryParameters(from: url) else { return }

            }
        }
    }
```

Parse url by this function:

```
static func queryParameters(from url: URL) -> [String: String]? {
    let urlComponents = URLComponents(url: url, resolvingAgainstBaseURL: false)
    var queryParams: [String : String]? = nil
    if let components = urlComponents?.queryItems {
      queryParams = [String: String]()
      for queryItem in components {
        if queryItem.value == nil {
          continue
        }
        queryParams?[queryItem.name] = queryItem.value
      }
    }
    return queryParams
  }
```

Comment: `queryParameters` is helpful to me for new version of firebase

Answer (score 0):

You should use `application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool`

Note that you have no **return** statement in your method

```
func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
    print("Got from URL: \(url)"
    return true
}
```

Links in simulator best to be done through terminal

```
xcrun simctl openurl booted “carwasher://deeplink”
```

Comment: thank you for answering . I copied your code but the app opens through deep link but that function doesn't get called and nothing will be printed

Comment: Try change role in Info tab from Viewer to Editor

Answer (score 0):

For me in iOS13+ the following works (in my `SceneDelegate`):

```
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
    // Set up everything you need
    // ...
    
    // Handle deep link on cold start
    if let url = connectionOptions.userActivities.first?.webpageURL {
        handle(url: url)
    }
}

func scene(_ scene: UIScene, continue userActivity: NSUserActivity) {
    if let url = userActivity.webpageURL {
        // Handle deep link when the app is running
        handle(url: url)
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You should configure your deeplinks in Info.plist file

Example:

```
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
            <string>Viewer</string>
            <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
            <string>carwash</string> // your identifier
            <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
            <array>
                <string>carwash</string> // schema
            </array>
        </dict>
    </array>
```

Comment: Its Already Declared . I can Open The App With deep link but I can't handle it